# How to run rails s -p80 on 80 port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

By default,

```
 rails s #running on 3000 port
```

Now I want to run it on port 80. So I tried:

```
 sudo rails -s -p80
```

But it threw an error:

```
mlzboy@mlzboy-MacBook ~/my/b2c2 $ sudo rails s -p80
sudo: rails: command not found
```

I used rvm to install ruby & rails. It seems rvm is user specified. Is it not able to find rails in root?

I also tried below code:

```
mlzboy@mlzboy-MacBook ~/my/b2c2 $ which rails
/home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rails
mlzboy@mlzboy-MacBook ~/my/b2c2 $ sudo /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rails s -p80
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
rvmsudo rails server -p 80
```

Comment: @pinouchon it works because `rvmsudo` does sudo plus loading rvm as sudo.

Comment: If like me you're using rbenv rather than rvm, this rbenv plugin will do the equivalent: https://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo

Comment: Would this be more of a risk if there’s a security hole in RVM, given that it’s running as root?

Comment: @Kevin Chen: Not in RVM, but I would be worried about running Rails as root. In production you would use Apache or Nginx, which needs root permissions to claim the port, but runs as a special user. My solution is just for testing things out in development.

Comment: I tired this but getting the `socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:80 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)` error

Comment: @r15 that means that you already have something else running on port 80.

Comment: thanks I resolved the error. my apache is running on 80

Comment: @micapam You should post that as an answer (about rbenv).

Answer (score 24):

Just forward the request from port 80 to 3000 using below command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

Another option is:

```
rvmsudo rails server -p 80
```

However please remember to free this port from Apache or other services which consume this port normally. Also, I m not sure giving sudo permission to RVM may have any security issue or not?

Comment: This will consume two ports, and it will not allow to run another ruby instance on port 3000.

Comment: How do you reverse this? It works perfectly for me, which is great, but what if I want to undo the redirect?

Thanks.

Comment: need to reset the IP route table to default

Comment: You can reverse this command by replacing the `-I` with `-D`, so `sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000`.  The answers here go into more detail: https://serverfault.com/questions/159544/undoing-port-forwarding .

Answer (score 9):

Was going to suggest

```
rails=`which rails` ; sudo $rails server -p 80
```

but that still tries to use the global gemset and not the project gemset from RVM.  So...

1. Make sure sshd is running on your Mac. (System Prefs => Sharing => Remote Login checked)
2. Make sure `rails s` is running on port 3000 as your non-root user
3. Open a new terminal and...

   ``` me=``whoami``; sudo ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:3000 -l $me -N localhost ```

(BTW reduce the duplicate `'s to singular ones in the line above, I cannot figure out how escape it properly here.)

The first `Password:` is your `root` user, the second is the password for whomever `whoami` returns.

Though you probably want to install Phusion Passenger and set it up under your local Apache.  Unless you are just trying to demo something real quick and this is not a permanent solution of course.

Comment: make sure you use `/usr/bin/which rails` in case rails is aliased

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RVM, and you did the default setup, then you shouldn't use `sudo`.

Just:

```
mlzboy@mlzboy-MacBook ~/my/b2c2 $ rails server -p 80
```

However 80 is a privileged port, so you *need* to run as root, and you will have follow the instructions for [Multi-User installation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) of RVM.

Comment: root is required for privileged ports.

Comment: @cfeduke - Oh! Right you are.

Comment: @marimaf - The documentation has matured over the time. Here is the new link: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: Thank you, this helps with accessing a MAC VM from a pc host to test a rails app i was working on. In that case though i did have to use the -b (bind) option with the vm's ip address.

Answer (score -1):

you can start server on port 80

```
rails s -p 80
```

If port 80 does not bind(other processes is not using to port 80).

Comment: Port below 1024 needs root access and you can't run application until you have not setup rails via root URL. I have implemented and test it.